# ERROR: Column 'id' not found while using NativeQuery in Hibernate 5.4.14

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-native-query

I've following query :

```
try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
    var clients = session.createNativeQuery("select c.fullname, c.city from client c where c.id=:id")
            .addEntity("c", Client.class)
            .setParameter("id", id);
```

and there's filed id in entity and in a database too but getting

```
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.`
```

Here's entity class:

```
public class Client  implements java.io.Serializable {    

     private Integer id;
     private Product product;
     private String fullname;
     private String business;
     private String address;
```

Here's Client.hbm.xml :

```
<class name="javafxapplication.pojo.Client" table="client" catalog="clientie" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
```

[image]

I'm using MySQL 8.0.21 Hibernate 5.4.14 JDK 11.0.8+10
I don't want to use JPA Criteria query cuase I'm using NativeQuery to check performance.
So don't suggest JPA

Comment: How is your database table set up? Have you tried with `.addEntity("client", Client.class)`?

Comment: So how is your database table?